# Create a text file in linux terminal using input from a different text file

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a text file, lets call it file A, and I need to create a new text file (file B) that contains only the first 3, and last 3 lines of file A, separated by three periods (...)

So if I type "cat file B", it should show:

```
 File A Line 1 
 File A Line 2 
 File A Line 3 
 ...
 File A 3rd last line
 File A 2nd last line 
 File A last line
```

I'm new to linux and the lecturer is not good at explaining these things. really not sure. The lesson is about I/O Redirection and text manipulation

Comment: What do you want to do when file A has only 2 lines?  What do you want to do if file A has 5 lines?

Comment: I suppose the purpose of this exercise is just to group commands.  If `cmd1` is the command to write the first 3 lines of the file (eg, `head -n 3 $path`) and `cmd2` is the command to write the last 3 lines of the file, you could do `{ cmd1; echo ...; cmd2; } > B`

Comment: file A is a text version of a book, it has 100s of lines. The question is very specific to this lab and it doesn't need to work for every file

Comment: Or, you could do 3 separate commands and use 2 different redirections. `cmd1 > fileB; echo ... >> fileB; cmd2 >> fileB`  (The `>>` redirect appends, while the `>` redirect truncates/creates a file)

Answer (score 0):

`file_a`

```
file_a line 1
file_a line 2
file_a line 3
file_a line 4
file_a line 5
file_a line 6
file_a line 7
file_a line 8
file_a line 9
```

I would just do three simple redirect commands:
`head -3 file_a > file_b`
`echo ... >> file_b`
`tail -3 file_a >> file_b`

the `head` command shows the first 10 lines by default. adding the `-3` flag will limit that to only 3 lines. but instead of displaying it on screen we use `>` to redirect it into file_b which at this point doesn't exist but the redirect will create the file.

```
file_a line 1
file_a line 2
file_a line 3
```

next is similar, we use `echo` which would also normally display to the screen but we redirect the output using `>>`. note that this is a double angled bracket. this will append our `echo` to the end of the file without overwriting our first three lines.

```
file_a line 1
file_a line 2
file_a line 3
...
```

last we have `tail`. similar to `head` except the opposite. this will normally output the last 10 lines to the screen but once again, we limit the output to only 3 using the `-3` flag and then redirect without overwriting using the `>>`

```
file_a line 1
file_a line 2
file_a line 3
...
file_a line 7
file_a line 8
file_a line 9
```